# How can I remove HTML quotes from my array?

Tags: php

How can I add `preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", html_entity_decode($s));` to `$data`. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

```
$date = date('m-d-Y');

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MD-Beaches-".$date.".csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

include('config.php');

$sql ="select county.title,beach.beach_name,beach.description,beach.latitude,beach.longitude,beach.status_id from beach as beach,county as county where beach.county_id=county.id ";

//$data[] = array("County","Beach Name","Description","Latitude","Longitude","RainFall","Temperature","Satus","Notice");    
$data[] = array("County","Beach Name","Description","Latitude","Longitude","Satus");    

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)) {
    $data[] = $row; // Inside while loop
}

outputCSV($data);

function outputCSV($data) {
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($data as $rowc) {
        fputcsv($output, $rowc);
    }
    fclose($output);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to call the `preg_replace()` statement on each element of `$data`: use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) with a callback function:

```
$data = array_map(function($elem) {
    return preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", html_entity_decode($elem));
}, $data);

outputCSV($data);
```